# Alignment issue in Repeater

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Below code is the repeaters's header row with database values. I want to align this as four columns. I tried but error is showing.

```
   <div id='h<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex") %>' class="heder"
      onclick='ToggleDisplay(<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex") %>);' style="border-style: none; font-weight: normal;">
     <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" Height="30px" BorderStyle="None" BackColor="White">
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnItemIndex" runat ="server" Value='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container, "ItemIndex") %>' />
     <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LicenseID")%>  
     <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Width="230px"></asp:HyperLink>                

     <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "StartDate")%>
         <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server" Width="150px"></asp:HyperLink>
     <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Renewal")%>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" Width="150px"></asp:HyperLink>
    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LicenseName")%>
   </asp:Panel> 
   </div>
```

Comment: Let's start with what the error says...

Comment: i want to allign the database values in a panel so that if value change also allignment won't go.

Comment: I give up.. I want to allign the database values inside the panel.

Comment: You said an error is showing, what is that error?  The SO community can not run your code, and rely on you to provide the information necessary to understand the problem.  If you are having styling issues than perhaps post the html on http://jsfiddle.net/ so it can be inspected.

Comment: sorry...Actually error is not showing but one detail division is opening always when When I use table.
Instead of table can I use any other controls  so that the database value will be in order(regardless of the value) and on mouse over show hand symbol

Comment: In the repeater 2 divisions are there with toggle function.I want this allignmetn in the heder division